# Drawing to a SurfaceView is low resolution

Tags: android, canvas

I have been tearing my hair out with this one. I am trying to make a Pong application (because we need another one of them, don't we?) in which everything looks rectangular and retro. Because of the rectangularization, I managed to get very far into the development of the application before I decided to add a textual notification of the current score. Upon doing so, I noticed that the canvas (or at least the text) was being drawn at a lower resolution than that which is native to my device (Nexus 4).

I have tried using the anti-alias flag, and while this gives a smoother look to the text, I can still see that it is not as sharp as it should be. To isolate the problem somewhat, I tried drawing some test circles to the canvas (one with anti-aliasing and one without). Lo and behold, the circles too were low resolution.

[image: The offending text and circles]

So far as I can tell, I have implemented the surface view correctly. Any parts of code required can be given.

Thanks.

Here is the code for the text style as well as the drawing of the text:

```
textStyle = new Paint(Paint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
textStyle.setColor(0xffffffff);
textStyle.setAntiAlias(true);
textStyle.setSubpixelText(true);

// draw from the bottom left up (lowest most recent)
Rect textBoundingRect = new Rect();
textStyle.getTextBounds(message, 0, message.length(), textBoundingRect);
// draw the text at the bottom of the screen
int top = (int) Math.round((c.getHeight() - (textBoundingRect.height() + 10) * i) );

// c is just the canvas that was returned from locking
c.drawText(m.getMessage(), 10, top, textStyle);
```

Comment: What's the radius of the circle?  If it's small and being scaled up significantly then you're going to see this.  Similarly, if you're rendering the text at a small point size and scaling up, it'll look jagged.

Comment: I am drawing the circles and text directly to the canvas by using Canvas.drawText and Canvas.drawCircle. At no point am I scaling anything up. I have added the appropriate code for the text in the OP.

Comment: Has anyone got anything on this one? I've found some odd things. Firstly, I found that if I print the value of the surface width in the onCreate function, I get the value of 320. This is strange, considering my phone screen width in pixels is 720. Secondly, if I force the SurfaceHolder to have the 720 x 1080 resolution then it looks much better, however the touch events are still messed up because I get a value of 320 for the x value of the touch when my finger is on the farthest right portion of the screen. Please, someone help me get to the bottom of this. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like something isn't quite right with the SurfaceView setup.  Given that Pong isn't too far removed from Breakout, you might want to look at https://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/ .

Comment: Unfortunately, that breakout clone is written using OpenGL ES. Maybe I should learn how to use OpenGL instead. It's fairly frustrating though, as I have another project in which I have a similar scaling issue, but I know that OpenGL is overkill for what I require. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Overkill is fun. :-)  The real question is, what will you be using to write games a year from now?

Comment: Absolutely agreed. However the other project in question has a deadline; not the kind of project I want to experiment on ;)

Comment: You've seen this? http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/09/using-hardware-scaler-for-performance.html

Comment: Looks like this is exactly what I'm supposed to do. I had actually tried the setFixedSize function before, but I couldn't get the width and height of the view for the aforementioned reasons. I suppose I'll just make the app fullscreen and get the screen width and height. Thanks very much, you've been a real help this whole time.

Comment: Although I'm giving up on this. There is a whole load more issues involving retrieving the width and height of the screen, touch positions and other positional issues resulting from the app believing that the width of the screen is 320 pixels. I'll learn OpenGL, w/e.

Comment: GL is fun!  And really, really complicated!  More examples (featuring `GLSurfaceView`, `SurfaceView`, and `TextureView`, in case you haven't had enough of the view system): https://github.com/google/grafika .  FWIW, you've inspired me to add "write an activity that fiddles with `setFixedSize()`" to my to-do list.

Comment: Added ("Hardware scaler exerciser").  Size can be changed on the fly with radio buttons.  The 64x100 resolution takes me back to my youth. :-)

Comment: I guess there's no interpolation on the scaling then?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  The scene is rendered at the "fixed" resolution, then the final buffer is scaled by whatever means the device chooses to use.  On my Nexus 5, the hardware composer is scaling it from 106x64 to 1794x1080 during scan-out, so there is no buffer anywhere in the system that has the 1794x1080 image.  At any rate, I wanted to let you know that the inspiration you provided has led to concrete results. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem by placing the SurfaceView within a parent FrameLayout.